# Passing structure to function

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, parameters

I have a function in c++ that needs a structure to work, but I
have a hard time passing it. The structure looks like this:

```
struct RecAbbo{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int games;
    int won;
    int same;
    int lost;
    int place;
    int money;
}Abbo[100];
```

First I tried this:

```
void function(structure_name);
```

That did not work so I searched the internet. I found that you should do it like this:

```
void function(structure_name struct);
```

But it didn't work.

How do I do it?

Comment: What is `structure_name`?

Comment: If you'd pass `Abbo`, you need an interface that can handle an array of structs, not just a struct.

Comment: It is the name of the structure so in my case it's: "Abbo"

Comment: how do I make the interface

Comment: @codermaster `Abbo` is a variable name, not the name of your struct, that one's called `RecAbbo`.

Comment: Yeah i changed that to RecAbbo but it still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for both `name` and `surname`, and also use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for the `Abbo` array:

```
struct RecAbbo {
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int games;
    int won;
    int same;
    int lost;
    int place;
    int money;
};
std::array<RecAbbo, 100> Abbo;
```

you can declare a function `func` that accepts a `RecAbbo` by reference or by `const` reference:

```
void func(RecAbbo&);
void func(RecAbbo const&);
```

The latter is recommended if you are not planning on modifying the `struct`.

If you want to pass the array, you can use:

```
void func(std::array<RecAbbo, 100>&);
void func(std::array<RecAbbo, 100> const&);
```

or generalize it with *iterators*:

```
template<class It>
void func(It begin, It end);
```

or with templates:

```
template<std::size_t Size>
void func(std::array<RecAbbo, Size>&);

template<std::size_t Size>
void func(std::array<RecAbbo, Size> const&);
```

Comment: gives this error   structure.cpp:94: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token   when executing the function

Comment: @codermaster, can you show the code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)? (click "share" once you have pasted it, and post the link)

Comment: here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3095c5a760515663 here is also pastebin if you want: http://pastebin.com/dryGx3bF

Comment: @codermaster, can you trim it down and reproduce the error for me?

Comment: @codermaster, remember to include both `<string>` and `<array>`.

Comment: @codermaster, `void safe(RecAbbo);` should be `void safe(RecAbbo&);`.

Comment: @codermaster, and see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cf8d35c61e0c7bc) for the commented version, where I explain what I did. In conjunction with my answer you should be able to understand. But if you have any more doubts, feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks. So if I want to use it in an other function i can just copy the header.

Comment: what about other functions/statements that use the 'Abbo' and how about this line:      if (strcmp(Abbo[i1].name, "/0") == 0 || strcmp(Abbo[i2].name, "/0") == 0){

Comment: @codermaster, for the other functions that use "Abbo" you should generalize them to accept a generic container (like we did above with the use of *iterators*) and pass `Abbo` to them like we did above. For the `strcmp` you do: `Abbo[i1].name == "/0"` or `Abbo[i2].name == "/0"`; but what you probably meant is `\0`, in which case you can just check if the string is empty with `Abbo[i1].name.empty()`.

Comment: I still get some errors that IT isen't decleared in the function and function headers. and the empty thing isen't working. gives an error that empty isen't a part of Abbo.

Comment: @codermaster that's because it's `It` not `IT` in my example. And `std::string` is the class that has a member function called [`empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: yeah but It gets not decleared the one from your example

Comment: @codermaster, `template<class It>` is the declaration of a type named `It`.

Comment: is there than something like a header I mised because I have that

Comment: @codermaster, can you reproduce the error for me, please?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a1c6f548ba63df9 I use geany on linux terminal server project. maybe that is the problem

Comment: @codermaster that's because `template<class It>` needs to prefix *every* function that uses `It` separately (see [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efcf0993ca08b314)). Also template functions cannot be split in header and source files. I'd recommend for you to read on [function templates here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template).

Comment: I get some other errors on the code. you want to take a look: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c43ee61caf6df9e6

Comment: I still have some errors with these lines: 'array<RecAbbo, 100> arr;' and: 'in.getline( Abbo[i].name, 20 ).ignore( std::numeric_limits< std::streamsize >::max(), '\n' );' also it can' call this function: 's = safe(arr.begin(), arr.end());'

Answer (score 3):

It should be other way around

```
void function(struct RecAbbo structure_name)
```

Also, make sure your struct is defined before the prototype of the function *function* as the prototype uses it.

But in C++, you don't need to use struct at all actually. So this can simply become:

```
void function(RecAbbo structure_name)
```

Comment: It comes up with this error.        structure.cpp:94: error: expected primary-expression before 'structure_name'

Comment: struct RecAbbo should be defined beforehand. Can you post the original code ?

Comment: What is structure_name in safe(RecAbbo structure_name) ? Its just a parameter to the function but where is it defined. I think you might want to send "Abbo" instead .

Comment: Nope gives me this: structure.cpp:94: error: conversion from ‘RecAbbo*’ to non-scalar type ‘RecAbbo’ requested

Comment: The variable "Abbo" is defined globally, it can be used anywhere. Eventhough you are sending structure_name as a parameter you were not really using it inside "safe". Please understand function parameters and global variables. Also, delete you other comments in here, comments section should not be this long.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
void function(RecAbbo any_name_for_object);
```

This will work.

Comment: with 'any_name_for_object' you mean that I have to call all objects?

Comment: No...name for object is just like a variable name. In your case structure is ReacAbbo so to access this structure you have to make object(variable) of that structure. Please go through this  [Link] (http://goo.gl/CJz7ca)   Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: @Deva: URL shorteners are not to be used on Stack Overflow as their target is hard to determine.

Comment: @hexafraction ohh Ok! Thanks for your suggestion. Will not do it in future :)